# How to login user to asterisk & maintain user/agent session?

Tags: php, asterisk, sip, voip, telephony

I'm working on telephony PBX VOIP Project (call center suite)

along with Asterisk/Linux specialist.

I'm Intermediate PHP developer. I'm stuck on very First step.

I've to connect agents to Asterisk using HTML & PHP & Mysql.

Can any one guide me Step by Step ? How to login & maintain session with asterisk ?

I want to accomplish following tasks in first week

1) Login Agent/s & connection with asterisk

2) After login & maintain Agent Session

3) I want to Redirect user to Campaign Page with status "Pause" or "Not Ready"

Comment: you can simply start from existing php packages. Either use them or see how it's done and implement your own solution https://github.com/OdinsHat/asterisk-php-manager or follow examples on voip-info https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-manager-example-php/

Comment: @MateiMihai Thanks for guiding, just wondering is PAMI https://github.com/marcelog/PAMI is good to start ? & where & when to use sip in telephony setup?

Answer (score 1):

Asterisk is PBX, main goal is manage calls, not provide you "very simple" api for access it.

If you want work with asterisk, you HAVE understand how dialplan and channels works, so you need read general book like ORelly's "Asterisk the future of telephony".

After that you can use db-driven dialplan or **AGI** script(but still need dialplan).

You also can use **AMI** interface or **ARI**(very similar to REST you know).

But anyway for any control method you have understand dialplan, sorry.

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Getting+Started+with+ARI

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Getting+Started+with+ARI

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/AMI+Libraries+and+Frameworks

Answer (score -1):

bro sorry to tell you here you post code errors and they will tell the answer if you want to learn than go to brad Traversy Tutorials and if you wanna do it on some MVC like Laravel then use

php artisan make:Auth